# JS: var = _window = window?

Tags: javascript, iife

I've seen variables created like this a few times and the same with the document object as well. it's often within a life like this

```
(function () { var _window = window; })();
```

I'm curious to know what they achieve by doing so instead of just using the window object.

Comment: It doesn't do anything because it throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

Comment: The code you posted is not valid Javascript. The variable name is missing between `var` and the first `=`.

Comment: _window was the name my bad